# Trouble configuring GoogleTest with CMake in Visual Studio - "Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h'"

Tags: c++, c, cmake, header, googletest

I'm currently facing issues including the GoogleTest header file (#include <gtest/gtest.h>) in C++ files within the "tests" and "src" directories of my project. Below are the relevant details:

Project Structure:

```
Root Directory:
- CMakeLists.txt
- tests
  - test_main.cpp
  - calc_test.cpp
- src
  - calc.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project("EX1") # Replace 

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/calc.cpp # this is where the code we want to test
)

set(TEST_FILES
    tests/test_main.cpp # this is the main for tests
    tests/calc_test.cpp # this file contains the tests
)

add_executable(CalcTests ${TEST_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(CalcTests PRIVATE gtest gtest_main)

target_include_directories(CalcTests PRIVATE src)

include(GoogleTest)
add_test(NAME CalcTests COMMAND CalcTests)
```

calc.test.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "../src/calc.cpp" // here we include the code to be tested
TEST(SumTest, BasicTest) {
    EXPECT_EQ(sum(1,2), 3);
}
```

test_main.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

To conclude,the last 2 files can't find `gtest.h`

Comment: Don't tag C++ question as C.

Comment: Don't link `gtest_main` if you define own function `main`.

Comment: Don't do that `#include "../src/calc.cpp"`, never include .cpp files.

Comment: The shown code compiles well except `error: 'sum': identifier not found`. Please post a [mcve]. Ensure your issue is replicable with the code posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with CMake. If you look closer at [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest) you see it supports also a second build system named [Bazel](https://bazel.build/install). I suggest to switch to Bazel (not sure if this is an option for you) since this makes the use of Google Test much easier:

Create a `MODULE.bazel`:

```
bazel_dep(name = "googletest", version = "1.14.0")
```

Create a `BUILD.bazel`:

```
cc_test(
    name = "tests",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
)
```

Create a `.bazelrc`:

```
build --enable_platform_specific_config

build:linux --cxxopt=-std=c++20 
build:macos --cxxopt=-std=c++2a 
build:windows --cxxopt=/std:c++20
```

Create a `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Now run `bazel test //...`

The nice thing here is that Bazel does cache the test results, e.g. it only re-executes a test if it has changed. Also test results can shared using a remote cache. If your workmate runs a test you do not have to re-run it - you get the cached result form the remote cache server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as u mention, I must use CMake...